# Using Yii2 frontend user signup in the backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii2 advanced template, they have the signup components for new users in the frontend.

I want to put that signup process into the /backend so that only admin users can create other new users.

So in moving SignupForm, signup view, adding the Signup action to the backend/SiteController, I'm getting 403 error "You are not allowed to perform this action".

Has anyone been able to put the signup process into the backend of the advanced template in Yii2 ?

What I want to do is have admin users create the new user and give the login details to the external party.  The external party would then be advised to run the Password Reset, in order to set their own password. But effectively, its locking down the registration/signup process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its nothing that should stop you from making this work. But will need to change a few things along the way.

First off, I guess your error message comes from the AccessControl that the backend SiteController has:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Change this to:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Orelse this will result in the error message:

```
Forbidden (#403)
You are not allowed to perform this action.
```

Remember that the signup function is made for guests registering, and that it automatically out-of-the box log the user in when the account is created.
You have to remove this feature, and you might encounter some other bugs along the way.

Good Luck.